# "the" before of-phrases

Tags: definite-article, possessives

I feel most the time there is a "the" before of-phrases

Consider the following sentence I wrote:

> As an example of the role of the context in **the classification of a node**, suppose we want to remove the navigation links in the sidebar.

Is "*the classification of a node*" correct? Does "*classification*" need "the"? Why?

I can imagine "*the user of the application*" or "*the man who is tall*" are specific, but can't imagine how "*classification*" is specific, then what would be the meaning of "*..the role of the context in classification of a node...*"

Comment: *classification* is a specific process (in context), so I would use *the*. You might add why you consider it unnecessary.

Comment: @user3169 I described it more.

Comment: Also the noun "context" is mass by definition, so no *the*, just "of context". I think using *the* in "the classification" is optional, depending on how you view the meaning of *classification".

Comment: Context is a mass noun, but it can also refer to separate entities. The context of singing in church is very different from the context of singing in a mosh pit, for instance, so context can take a definite article. But in the above sentence it is not necessary.