# Use of "the" before the first part of Of-phrases

Tags: definite-article, of-phrases

There is a [similar question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/use-of-the-before-of-phrases) with a similar title, however it then focused on two specific examples. The main question is when we should use "the" before an Of-phrase.

Is "the" used for the first part or the whole phrase? 
for example, is it [the history ] of the internet. Or the [history of the internet ].

Some examples by searching google:

> - the International Day of the Girl Child
> - the study of Pattern Recognition
> - The Charter of the United Nations
> - More than 60 United Nations Member States have never been **Members of the Security Council**.
> - the Word of the Day
> - The history of the Internet
> - Transactions of the American Mathematical Society
> - Proceedings of the Royal Society
> - Types of problems and tasks

For example in

> Machine learning is a subfield of computer science that evolved from the study of pattern recognition and computational learning theory in artificial intelligence.

Why "the study". Please note there is not much context for the "study" and I suspect the possessive construction has a role.

Apart from these examples, I feel in Of-phrases the domain of objects become limited, and it allows to use "the" for the noun before "of". For example you can't say "the mouse"! which mouse? but you can say "the mouse of a computer" because in the domain of a single computer, mouse is specific.

For another example we may say "The manager of a shop" (even without any context) but not "the customer of the shop" (again without any context). maybe "the customers of the shop" or maybe just "customers of the shop". "the door of the house" but not "the window of the house", because without any context we don't have one window but one door. Similarly, "the head of a human" but not "the hand of a human" (maybe the left hand of a human).

Does this analysis creditable?

Comment: I don't think there's any special rule for using "the" before *of*-phrases.  It's the same principle for why we would use "the" anywhere else.  Also, why do you think we couldn't say "the window of the house" or "the hand of a human"?  Those are perfectly correct phrases.

Comment: **Members** is a role. About 99% of students have never been valedictorian of their class.

Comment: Role noun. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jy9rbMGSPl4

Comment: @stangdon everyone has one head then we know which head in the head of a human but when you say the finger of me, it's not known which finger unless there is a context. Isn't it? It is just an example .

Comment: @Mari-LouA I described it in the question.

Comment: @Ahmad You can say *the finger of me* but in reality *my finger* is the way to refer to one's own finger. You might hear *this finger of mine* in certain contexts such as storytelling, but *the finger of me* is grammatical but little-used. Even with ***my finger*** the context would have to determine which finger is meant.

Comment: *The window of the house* is just as natural as *the door of the house*, even when there are multiple windows and only one door*. Of course, *the window of the house* could refer to a house's only window: it  depends on context. In fact, the use/meaning of articles is largely dependent on context. Single sentences are rarely enough to illustrate native usage.

Comment: A problem with analyzing these examples is that we don't know if they are part of headlines. In headlines, articles are often omitted. Again, article usage is context dependent and listing noun phrases does little to help people answer your question.

Comment: @stangdon I added some example. You say the rule is the same. Why it is "the study of ...'?

Comment: @AlanCarmack most of-phrase I saw are like "the X of Y". I wonder why other can't see this pattern. I also said without any context in a possessive construction if the first part (please tell me what's the term for it) is unique for the second part "the" is used. Forget any context.

Comment: @Ahmad - The principle is the same everywhere.  We say "**the** study of" because it's a specific study of a specific field, not just any study.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["the" before of-phrases](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/64035/the-before-of-phrases) asked by the same user over a year ago. The lack of an answer back then may be due to the fact that there is no *rule* saying one has to use *the* before an *of-phrase*.

Comment: @AlanCarmack yes right. Now I feel possession itself has a role because it makes the noun more specific. I just need to get a node.

Comment: @stangdon OK then "study of PR" is a specific study. What is specific in "the head of a human"? I feel it is because each person have one head. These two examples are not similar.

Comment: @Ahmad - I think I might be starting to understand.  Can you give me an example of a complete sentence?  Sometimes context makes a lot of difference.  Are you asking why would say "**The** head of a human was on the mad scientist's table" but "**A** human head was on the mad scientist's table"?

Comment: @Ahmad I'd say that all examples in your question are possible (i.e., if *X of (a/the) Y* is grammatical, then *the X of (a/the) Y* would also be grammatical, but it heavily depends on context. (And as you know, it's tricky. Just changing a word or two here and there in your sentence or your excerpt may change everything, and sometimes more than one choice is possible.)

Comment: @AlanCarmack I don't believe we should close this question as a duplicate of the older one simply because this one is newer (and especially when the older question has no answer). I think this is the better written of the two, so I'm going to close the older one as a duplicate of this one and leave this one open to see if we can get an answer that Ahmad is comfortable accepting.

Comment: @stangdon I once again explained it in my question. I think when we are restricted to a single human, we can say "the head of a human" can't we? because we are talking about a human and head is a specific part of him, what makes this to happen? the possessive phrase.

Comment: @stangdon the example can be " Brain is located in the head of a human".

Answer (score 3):

Nouns can have prepositional phrases after them that qualify the noun further. Those prepositional phrases may themselves have objects, which are additional nouns.

However, this does not usually create a new rule or requirement.  Rules for articles is applied separately to both nouns.

In "X of Y", it's more likely than usual that Y may be a kind or type, which won't take an article, but you can't automatically assume that.

> Apart from these examples, I myself think if just one specific thing is possessed by another object then the first noun gets "the". for example we may say "The manager of the shop" but not "the customer of the shop" maybe "the customers of the shop" or maybe just "customers of the shop". "the door of the house" but not "the window of the house". "the head of a human" but not "the hand of a human".

None of this is true.  You can use *the* after *of* in all these cases.

Comment: Thank you! I added further examples to my question, I didn't say "the" after "of", but "the" for the noun before "of".

Comment: you also said, articles are applied separately to both nouns. In "the study of PR", if I remove "of PR", then I think "the" is not applicable to "study". Then it may apply to "study of PR" which is an specific study. However in "the mouse of the computer", it can be applied separately, Still the one-to-one relation between "mouse" and "computer" has an effect on the "the mouse". However I agree, that "the computer" obeys the general rule of articles.

Comment: Nouns that represent general areas of study don't take articles.  "I study mathematics," "We are talking about mathematics."  Doesn't matter whether it's involved with *of* or not.

Comment: We don't say "the study of mathematics"? There are lot of [results for that](https://www.google.com/search?q=the+study+of+mathematics&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b#q=%22+*+the+study+of+mathematics%22), please note I am talking about the noun before "of" (*study*) not after it.

Comment: We don't say "The study of the mathematics."

Comment: I know we don't say "the mathematics" and really don't care it in this question. my question is about "the study".

Comment: There's no special rule saying you can't use *the* with *study* after of.  A good reference for understanding why articles aren't used can be found if you search for "zero article" on Wikipedia.  Articles are not used if the singular noun is a type (e.g. answering the question "which kind?"), concept, or meant in a general sense.  In an expression like "field of study", *study* is meant in a general sense.  There is no instance of study that exists.